# Programmatically showing a ToolTip

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I have developed a WPF sample project.

Here is the main Window's XAML markup :

```
<Window x:Class="ToolTipSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Click="OnButtonClick">Show ToolTip</Button>

        <StatusBar Grid.Row="2">
            <StatusBarItem>
                <TextBlock Text="TextBlock With ToolTip">
                    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Name="m_toolTip">
                            ToolTip
                        </ToolTip>
                    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                </TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the main Window's code-behind without the using statements :

```
namespace ToolTipSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnButtonClick(object p_sender, RoutedEventArgs p_args)
        {
            m_toolTip.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to programmatically show the ToolTip when the Button is clicked.
I want the ToolTip to be shown above its TextBlock parent.

The ToolTip is automatically shown when the mouse cursor is over the TextBlock and during a constant amount of time C approximatively equal to 5 seconds.
I want the ToolTip to be shown during C when the Button is clicked.

My goals are not achieved in the current project.
The ToolTip is shown when the Button is clicked :

[image]

But :

- The ToolTip is too far from its TextBlock parent.
- The ToolTip is not automatically hidden

What do I have to do to achieve my goals ?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have achieved my goals.
Sheridan's answer and comments help me.
I have updated my sample project.
The ToolTip is now shown just above the TextBlock when the Button is clicked.
And a Timer's callback method closes the ToolTip after a constant amount of time equal to 2500 ms.

Here is the updated main Window's XAML markup :

```
<Window x:Class="ToolTipSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Click="OnButtonClick">Show ToolTip</Button>

        <StatusBar Grid.Row="2">
            <StatusBarItem>
                <TextBlock Width="900" />
            </StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem>
                <TextBlock x:Name="m_statusMessage" Text="TextBlock With ToolTip" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="30000">
                    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Name="m_toolTip" Placement="Top">
                            <TextBlock>
                                ToolTip ToolTipToolTipToolTipToolTipToo lTipToolTipToolTipT oolTipToolTipT
                                <LineBreak />
                                oolTipToolTi pToolTipToo lTipToolTipToolTipToolTipToolTipTo olTipToolTipToolTipTool
                                <LineBreak />
                                TipToo lTipToolTipToolTipToo lTipToolTipTo olTipToolTip
                            </TextBlock>
                        </ToolTip>
                    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                </TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the updated main Window's code-behind without the using statements :

```
namespace ToolTipSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Timer m_toolTipClosingTimer;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            m_toolTipClosingTimer = new Timer(ToolTipClosingCallBack, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        private void OnButtonClick(object p_sender, RoutedEventArgs p_args)
        {
            m_toolTip.PlacementTarget = m_statusMessage;
            m_toolTip.IsOpen = true;
            m_toolTipClosingTimer.Change(2500, Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        private void ToolTipClosingCallBack(object p_useless)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    m_toolTip.IsOpen = false;
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You have a number of problems. The first and simplest to fix is that you are only opening and not closing the `ToolTip`. You said *I want the ToolTip to be shown during the same amount of time when the Button is clicked*, and this is easily implemented handling the `PreviewMouseDown` and `PreviewMouseUp` events:

```
private void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    m_toolTip.PlacementTarget = PlacementTarget;
    m_toolTip.IsOpen = true;
}

private void Button_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    m_toolTip.IsOpen = false;
}
```

...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button PreviewMouseDown="Button_PreviewMouseDown" 
        PreviewMouseUp="Button_PreviewMouseUp">Show ToolTip</Button>
    <StatusBar Grid.Row="2">
        <StatusBarItem>
            <TextBlock Name="PlacementTarget" Text="TextBlock With ToolTip">
                <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip x:Name="m_toolTip" Placement="Top" HorizontalOffset="50" 
                        VerticalOffset="-5">ToolTip</ToolTip>
                </TextBlock.ToolTip>
            </TextBlock>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

Your other problem is slightly more tricky to fix... it seems to me as though there may be some bug involved in the positioning of your `ToolTip`. Normally, despite what @icebat said, it *is* possible to alter the position of a `ToolTip` using the [`ToolTip.Placement` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip.placement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This can be set to one of the [`PlacementMode` Enumerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.placementmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The default value is `Mouse` and this is the definition from the linked page on MSDN:

> A postion of the Popup control that aligns its upper edge with the lower edge of the bounding box of the mouse and aligns its left edge with the left edge of the bounding box of the mouse. If the lower screen-edge obscures the Popup, it repositions itself to align with the upper edge of the bounding box of the mouse. If the upper screen-edge obscures the Popup, the control repositions itself to align with the upper screen-edge.

This explains why the `ToolTip` is displayed far from the `TextBlock` placement target... because the `Button` and therefore the mouse (when clicking) is far from the `TextBlock`. However, by setting the `Placement` property to another value should enable a wide range of positions to be achieved. However, setting different values of the `Placement` property alone, will just display the `ToolTip` in the top left corner of the screen.

To address this situation, you should also set the [`ToolTip.PlacementTarget` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip.placementtarget%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as @icebat correctly noted in the comment, but apparently only from code. Once the `PlacementTarget` property has been set, the `Placement` property value works as expected. From this linked page:

> You can position a ToolTip by setting the PlacementTarget, PlacementRectangle, Placement, HorizontalOffset, and VerticalOffsetProperty properties.

[image]

Comment: Great answer! I totally overlooked `Placement`, together with `PlacementTarget` they do the trick in my test project. But I had to set `PlacementTarget` on click cause otherwise it doesn\`t set correctly (ToolTip is not in the tree during init, that\`s the reason I guess).

Comment: @Sheridan I have implemented the handler of the Button's PreviewMouseDown event and the handler of the Button's PreviewMouseUp event as you describeb. But the ToolTip is not shown during few seconds as when the mouse cursor is over the TextBlock.

Comment: Add some breakpoints and debug your problem to see what is going on. My example works just fine, so yours *should* also be able to work fine.

Comment: +1 for mentioning setting the `PlacementTarget` property from code @icebat... it's an important part and so I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: It is... but that's because the question author said *I want the ToolTip to be shown during the same amount of time when the Button is clicked*. They seem to be saying there is some delay before the `ToolTip` is displayed, but that could be down to anything.

Comment: Nevermind, I tried your example, works fine. ToolTip stays until mouse leaves current control, exactly as when hovering above TextBlock. But I guess OP wants to stay it open for some time regardless of mouse movements, @Sheridan.

Comment: @Sheridan I have tried your example. My operating system is Windows 7 64 bits. The ToolTip is shown when the Button is clicked but the ToolTip is immediately hidden after the mouse left button is released. What is your operating system ?

Comment: I'm not sure how many times I can say this in one answer (and associated comments): You said *I want the ToolTip to be shown during the same amount of time when the Button is clicked*. In English, this means that you want the `ToolTip` to be displayed when the mouse button is first pressed and to be hidden when the mouse button is released. So that is exactly what I have provided you with. If you didn't want that, perhaps you should not have asked for that. `m_toolTip.IsOpen = false;` is what closes it, so if you want it to close later, move that line to a timer `Tick` handler, or similar.

Comment: @Sheridan I have edited my question. I have changed the text block which contained the following sentence : _I want the ToolTip to be shown during the same amount of time when the Button is clicked_.