# How to show Tooltip immediately without hovering of mouse? WPF, TextBox, IDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tooltip, idataerrorinfo

I've searched in the Internet for my obvious question and I haven't found  asnwers. I've read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2008/06/27/displaying-data-validation-messages-in-wpf.aspx) , [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/princy.scorpin/data-validation-in-wpf-using-idataerrorinfo-and-displaying-t/) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98681/Validating-User-Input-WPF-MVVM).

I've implemented IDataErrorInfo and user can see an error if mouse is hovered over textbox. However, I would like to show immediately when error occurs without hovering mouse. I have a canonical data template:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

My question is that **how to avoid need to hover over the edge to get the ToolTip to display?**

Comment: Maybe this could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673881/programmatically-showing-a-tooltip

Comment: @almulo it is not possible to use code behind for me.